# Does this code satisfy the concurrency requirement?

Tags: c++, multithreading, http, concurrency

I am following this [code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83632/minimal-webserver-in-c) of an C++ http server.  One of the requirement is concurrency.  That seems to be taken care of by the following chunk of code:

```
if(true) {
    if(pthread_create(&thread, 0, handle_request, pcliefd) < 0) {
            perror("pthread_create()");
        } 
    } else {
        handle_request(pcliefd);
    }
```

I then come across a simpler code in this [article](https://medium.com/from-the-scratch/http-server-what-do-you-need-to-know-to-build-a-simple-http-server-from-scratch-d1ef8945e4fa).  `pthread` is not used here.  The response is handle by a `write` nested inside `while(1)`.  I suppose this simpler code does not meet the concurrency requirement?  Anyways, what is the point of using thread to handle concurrency if the response is so simple?  Is there something bigger behind this requirement?

Comment: Concurrency and multithreading are two different things. You can write concurrent single threaded servers as well as non-concurrent multithreaded servers. From your small code snippet it is not possible to tell how the program works, and especially if it handles requests concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of your first linked question was to demonstrate a minimum of concurrency. Not a useful amount, just the bare minimum. Your second link doesn't even have that, as you correctly assumed.

Real webservers will be more complex. For starters, you don't want *too* much concurrency; there are only a limited number of CPU cores in your computer. See [`std::thread::hardware_conccurency`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency)

Answer (score 0):

> Anyways, what is the point of using thread to handle concurrency if the response is so simple?

This is actually a good question. The problem you face, when you want to handle a large number of clients is, that the `read()` and `write()` system calls are usually *blocking*. That means, they block your current thread as long as they take to complete the requested operation.

Say you have two clients, that send a request to your single threaded, non-concurrent server. Client A belongs to some lonely guy in a mountain hut with a real slow internet connection. Your `listen()` call returns and your program calls the handler routine for client A. Now while the bits slowly trickle through the mountain cable and your handler routine waits for the request to be transmitted, a second client B connects to your server. This one belongs to a business man at his high speed office internet access.

The problem here is, that even if your response is so simple, the high speed client still has to wait until your handler routine returns and can process the next request. One slow client can slow down all the other clients, which is obviously not what you want.

You can solve that problem using two approaches:

1. (that is the attempt in your code) you create a new thread for each client. That way if a slow client is blocking the handling routine for a long time, the other clients are still able to proceed with their request. The problem here is that a large number of clients creates a large number of threads. Context switching thousands of threads can be a massive performance issue. So for a small number of concurrent clients this is fine, but for large scale high performance servers we need something better.
2. You use a *non-blocking* API of the operating system. How exactly that works is different between operating systems. And even on a single OS there might exist different such APIs. Ususally you want to use a platform independed library if you need this type of concurrency support. An excellent library here is [Boost Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

The two approaches can be mixed. For the best performance you would want to have as many threads as you have processor cores. Each thread handles requests concurrently using and asynchronous (non-blocking) API. This is usually done with a worker pool and a task queue.

Comment: ... except that the Internet doesn't work as you describe. The `write` call blocks while the data is being transferred to your network card. It doesn't block on the downstream connection.

Comment: @MSalters You're right about the `write()` call. But `read()` will block. And if it doesn't, your handler routine will have to repeatedly call it. You need the http request before returning a response.

Comment: It's still a packet network, and HTTP request often fit in one packet. The 1 kB request will take several microseconds to arrive over your 1 Gb/s Ethernet, even if it took longer to send over the 56K phone line. You don't mention `select`, though, which is the classical solution for single-threaded servers. That is what prevents `read` from blocking on that single packet.

Comment: If you mention `select` you should also mention `epoll` and `io_uring` which are the more modern async interfaces with better performance.